# How to run different mocha test files one after another or more than 5 files in parallel?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, mocha.js

I am trying to make a Test Automation Cases with Mocha js, and facing an issue. When I try to run mocha test files parallel I can not run more than 5 files and if I try to run without the parallel flag, only first file in the Test folder runs.

How can I run Test Files sequentially with Mocha? Also if it is possible in Jenkins, how I can do it with Jenkins?